# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when trying to append to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, append, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to append values to my dictionary, but I can't solve this error.

This is my dictionary:

```
groups  = {'group1': array([450, 449.]), 'group2': array([490, 489.]), 'group3': array([568, 567.])}
```

then I have a txt file (loaded using np.loadtxt) with many data and I have to iterate over this file and if a certain condition is met I should add that line to the correct key of my dictionary.
I used the if statement and I called the data that met the condition "parent".

```
parent = [[449. 448.]] 
[[489. 488.]] 
[[567. 566.]]
```

I tried this:

```
for i, x in enumerate(parent):
        groups.setdefault(x, []).append(i)
```

expected output:

```
groups  = {'group1': array([450, 449.], [449, 448]), 'group2': array([490, 489.], [489, 488]), 'group3': array([568, 567.], [567, 566])}
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: You should read the doc of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#enumerate).

Comment: I did, and I was wondering if there is any other approach to get the result that I want...I have tried many different things and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Then you should decide which one of `i` and `x` is key of your dictionary. I believe you can solve it yourself. The error means data of type `ndarray` cannot be the key of a dictionary.

Comment: is there any other way to do it? not using enumerate?

Comment: I think `enumerate` is fine. Do my comments help you get rid of `TypeError`? Have you encountered a new problem?

Comment: still not able to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got this error is that you tried to use data of unhashable type `numpy.ndarray` as the key of a dictionary. The links below are useful for your question.

- [Mapping Types - `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

> A mapping object maps [**hashable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) values to arbitrary objects.

- [`dict.setdefault(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) - It invokes a hash operation on `key`.
- [exception `TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)

> Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type.

- [`enumerate(iterable, start=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#enumerate)

---

In your `for` loop, `i` is of type `int` which is hashable while `x` is of type `numpy.ndarray` which is unhashable. Therefore not using `x` as the `key` argument of `groups.setdefault` solves your `TypeError` problem.

P.S., there is still a way to go to get the expected `groups`. I don't show you the code, because it's not clear what the expected values of the dictionary are, a 2D array as value or a list of 1D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As ILS noted, the problem description is unclear:

1. are the output values a list or a 2D array?
2. is `parent` a list of lists or some sort of array?
3. is `parent`'s size the same as `groups`'s size?

Assuming same size lists, is this helping? -

```
groups  = {'group1': [[450., 449.]], 'group2': [[490., 489.]], 'group3': [[568., 567.]]}
parent = [[449., 448.],
[489., 488.],
[567., 566.]]
for i, x in enumerate(parent):
    groups[f'group{i+1}'].append(x)
groups
```

Returns:

```
{'group1': [[450.0, 449.0], [449.0, 448.0]],
 'group2': [[490.0, 489.0], [489.0, 488.0]],
 'group3': [[568.0, 567.0], [567.0, 566.0]]}
```

---

How about now? -

```
import numpy as np

groups  = {'group1': np.array([[450., 449.], [0,0]]), 'group2': np.array([[490., 489.], [0,0]]), 'group3': np.array([[568., 567.], [0,0]])}
parent = [[449., 448.],
[489., 488.],
[567., 566.]]
for i, x in enumerate(parent):
    groups[f'group{i+1}'][1] = x
groups
```

Returns:

```
{'group1': array([[450., 449.],
        [449., 448.]]),
 'group2': array([[490., 489.],
        [489., 488.]]),
 'group3': array([[568., 567.],
        [567., 566.]])}
```

Note that I initialized `groups` to a 2D array to avoid resizing.

---

Or, as an exercise, if you prefer using `np.append`:

```
groups  = {'group1': np.array([[450., 449.]]), 'group2': np.array([[490., 489.]]), 'group3': np.array([[568., 567.]])}
parent = [[449., 448.],
[489., 488.],
[567., 566.]]
for i, x in enumerate(parent):
    groups[f'group{i+1}'] = np.append(groups[f'group{i+1}'], np.array(x)[np.newaxis, ...], axis=0)
groups
```

Returns again:

```
{'group1': array([[450., 449.],
        [449., 448.]]),
 'group2': array([[490., 489.],
        [489., 488.]]),
 'group3': array([[568., 567.],
        [567., 566.]])}
```

---

An alternative with a different `parent` format:

```
groups  = {'group1': np.array([[450., 449.]]), 'group2': np.array([[490., 489.]]), 'group3': np.array([[568., 567.]])}
parent = [[[449., 448.]],
[[489., 488.]],
[[567., 566.]]]
for i, x in enumerate(parent):
    groups[f'group{i+1}'] = np.append(groups[f'group{i+1}'], x, axis=0)
groups
```

Please confirm what your data look like... I'm unfortunately just guessing.

---

Another approach, assuming `parent` is an array of size (1, 3, 2):

```
groups  = {'group1': np.array([[450., 449.]]), 'group2': np.array([[490., 489.]]), 'group3': np.array([[568., 567.]])}
parent = np.array([[[449., 448.],
[489., 488.],
[567., 566.]]])
parent.shape
parent[0,1]
for i, _ in enumerate(groups):
    groups[f'group{i+1}'] = np.append(groups[f'group{i+1}'], np.array(parent[0, i])[np.newaxis, ...], axis=0)
groups
```

Returns:

```
{'group1': array([[450., 449.],
        [449., 448.]]),
 'group2': array([[490., 489.],
        [489., 488.]]),
 'group3': array([[568., 567.],
        [567., 566.]])}
```

Comment: it gives me this error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: I get: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: I can only guess what you're running; you should provide more data. I wonder what format your `parent` object is: is it a list of lists or a list of lists containing one more level?? I'm posting an update reflecting this alternative...

Comment: parent is a nd-array

Comment: what shape? `parent.shape == (3, 2)` or `(3, 1, 2)`?

Comment: The dictionary contains 3 lists. I hope it's more clear....parent.shape = (1,  3)

Comment: wait, you said `parent` is an `ndarray`. My question is what shape it is. What dictionary are you referring to, `groups`? I understand it's a dictionary containing three `ndarray`s. What 3 lists do you mean? I'm utterly confused now.

Comment: if I check the shape I get parent.shape == (1, 3) 
for what concern the dictionary I supposed 'group1', 'group2' and 'group3' are arrays since when I print(groups) it gives me groups  = {'group1': array([450, 449.]) ..etc!
but if I check the shape of "group1" for example it returns (3, )..so maybe my  assumption was wrong. I'm sorry I'm new to programming not just to Python...

Comment: last update that you made didn't return any error, but it appends [[449., 448.],
[489., 488.],
[567., 566.]] (which are "parent") only to "group1" and the other two groups are unchanged

Comment: ok, let me try one more time :) it looks like `parent` has only one row and three columns, I'm guessing here the `parent` array has some `dtype` like 'object' or something because your `parent`'s values hold two floats which you want to append as rows to the `groups` arrays. So it sounds a bit unexpected. I'll try to simulate your situation as an array of shape `(1, 3, 2)` - check the updated answer and adjust for your needs. The code snippets work with the assumptions inside them, however, if your data are of different shape or type I can't do much :)

Comment: You are so patient and do a good job. You can simply ignore  the poster because he/she is asking additional questions. I'm sure the OP is asking how to solve the TypeError. If not, @Ludovica you should read [ask] carefully and provide an [mre]. When you ask a question, you should make it focused, clear, and reproducible, so that others can help you quickly and precisely, instead of clarifying it over and over again in the comments, wasting people's time.

Comment: @ILS thanks, I'm learning too but at this point I think the poster should be able to adapt some of the suggestions.

Comment: thank you @isCzech for your help..I would try to adapt what you suggested. 
Sorry if I wasted someone's time, I didn't mean to.

Comment: @ILS I will think more carefully before posting in the future, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Ludovica, that's ok. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74447402/edit) your post to improve it, just be sure you won't make it a quite different question. Or you can open new posts to describe your other questions. : ) A man who clicks this post probably won't read these comments to understand this answer.

Comment: I'd suggest you post a minimum working code snippet including a few data samples that can be run as a whole and studied instead of guessing what the data type and format are, what the array's shape is etc... For example, include a definition of a sample of `parent` and `groups` data, including your failing code so that the error can be replicated and fixed.